# What is ^M in Git?

Tags: git

I'll sometimes edit a line using my IDE (NuSphere's PhpED), and then return it to what I think is the original.  `git diff`, however, shows it as being changed with the only difference being a `^M` at the end.  What does `^M` signify?  Anything I could do to edit the code so it doesn't show up as a change?

```
- <td></td>
- <td><img […]></td>
+ <td></td>^M
+ <td><img […]></td> ^M
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something changed your line endings from Unix style to Windows. The ^M is a carriage return character. Check all your tools settings carefully!

Answer (score 2):

`^M` is one of the multiple representations of the [`carriage return` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return).

It is a white space character, it does not usually affect the code and the HTML.

It presence in your file is a sign that the file was edited/saved on a Windows system.